# Java open new ssh connection from already existing

Tags: java, ssh, connection, sftp, jsch

I am new in JAVA. 
I trying to write an application that will do next - open ssh connection to UNIX server and from this server connection to another server using private key.

To connect to first server I am using program like:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
String user = "john";
String password = "mypassword";
String host = "192.168.100.23";
int port=22;

try
    {
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    System.out.println("Establishing Connection...");
    session.connect();
        System.out.println("Connection established.");
    System.out.println("Crating SFTP Channel.");
    ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
    sftpChannel.connect();
    System.out.println("SFTP Channel created.");


    InputStream out= null;
    out= sftpChannel.get(remoteFile);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(out));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(line);
    br.close();
    }
catch(Exception e){System.err.print(e);}
}
```

And it works fine. But when I try to use the same code to connect to second this doesn't work, as application tries to create a completely new connection without using already created one.

Does someone know how can I forse application to use already created connection?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using port forwarding in the first `session` and then creating another `session` that connect to the host in the local port forwarded.  The example [JumpHosts.java](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/JumpHosts.java.html) does exactly that. For public key authentication refers to  [UserAuthPubKey.java](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/UserAuthPubKey.java.html)

This is a modification to your code based on those examples:

```
String user = "john";
String password = "mypassword";
String host = "127.0.0.1";
String host2 = "192.168.100.23";
int port=22;

try{
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session1 = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
    session1.setPassword(password);
    session1.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    System.out.println("Establishing Connection...");
    session1.connect();
    System.out.println("Connection established.");

    //Here we do port forwarding to the second host
    int assinged_port = session1.setPortForwardingL(0, host2, 22);
    System.out.println("portforwarding: "+
            "localhost:"+assinged_port+" -> "+host+":"+22);

    //And here we connect to the first host to the forwarded port, not 22
    Session session2 = jsch.getSession(user, host, assinged_port);

    //This is your public key file 
    jsch.addIdentity("~/.ssh/id_rsa");
    session2.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session2.connect();
    System.out.println("The session has been established to "+
            user+"@"+host);

    System.out.println("Crating SFTP Channel.");
    ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) session2.openChannel("sftp");
    sftpChannel.connect();
    System.out.println("SFTP Channel created.");


    InputStream out= null;
    out= sftpChannel.get(remoteFile);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(out));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(line);
    br.close();
}
catch(Exception e){System.err.print(e);}
```